# How can I show a hidden UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Views were placed using code.
If I press deleteButton (button), I want the hidden button(imgButton) to appear.

However, imgView's width is not refresh.

**MainViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    var trashIsSelected: Bool!

    let imgButton: UIButton = {
        let imgView = UIButton()
        imgView.setImage(UIImage(named: "schedule_delete_icon"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    //        imgView.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "schedule_delete_icon")
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imgView
    }()

    let deleteButton: UIButton = {
       let imgBtn = UIButton()
        imgBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_delete"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    //        imgBtn.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "icon_delete")
        imgBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imgBtn
    }()

    let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "하ㅣㅇ하이히아히아하하하하ㅏㅎ하ㅏㅎ하ㅏ하하하하ㅏㅏ하하하하하ㅏ"
        return label
    }()


    var imgViewWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupLayout()
    }


    func setupLayout(){
        let testView = UIScrollView()

        self.view.addSubview(testView)
        testView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true

        testView.addSubview(imgButton)
        testView.addSubview(label)
        imgButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        imgButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        imgButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
        imgButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgButton.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0).isActive = true
        imgButton.isHidden = true
        trashIsSelected = false

        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
        label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true




        self.view.addSubview(deleteButton)
        deleteButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        deleteButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.addBtnAction(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func addBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton){
        print("hi")
        if trashIsSelected == false{
            trashIsSelected = true
            imgButton.isHidden = false
            imgButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
            imgButton.updateConstraints()

        }else{
            trashIsSelected = false
            imgButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
            imgButton.isHidden = true
            imgButton.updateConstraints()
        }
    }
}
```

This is error message:

```
2018-05-23 14:00:47.697959+0900 Test[67488:4887863] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 

(
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 


Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding new constraints to the button that conflict with the old ones (how can a button be 0 points wide, and simultaneously 50 points wide?). To make it work, you need to turn off the old constraint before you activate a new one. I recommend creating a property that would keep the current `imgButton` constraint at all times, and then when you want to change it, just use that (either turn it off and create a new one, or just set a constant, which in your case is better and easier):

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    // property referencing current imgButton width constraint
    fileprivate var imgButtonWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var trashIsSelected: Bool!

    let imgButton: UIButton = {
        let imgView = UIButton()
        imgView.setImage(UIImage(named: "schedule_delete_icon"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        //        imgView.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "schedule_delete_icon")
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imgView
    }()

    let deleteButton: UIButton = {
        let imgBtn = UIButton()
        imgBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_delete"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        //        imgBtn.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "icon_delete")
        imgBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return imgBtn
    }()

    let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "하ㅣㅇ하이히아히아하하하하ㅏㅎ하ㅏㅎ하ㅏ하하하하ㅏㅏ하하하하하ㅏ"
        return label
    }()


    var imgViewWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupLayout()
    }


    func setupLayout(){
        let testView = UIScrollView()

        self.view.addSubview(testView)
        testView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3).isActive = true

        testView.addSubview(imgButton)
        testView.addSubview(label)
        imgButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        imgButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        imgButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true

        // keep the reference to constraint that defines width
        // (we will use the constraint setting the width to constant, since then you can
        // simply switch the constant between 0 and 50):
        imgButtonWidthConstraint = imgButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        imgButtonWidthConstraint.isActive = true

        imgButton.isHidden = true
        trashIsSelected = false

        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgButton.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).isActive = true
        label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true




        self.view.addSubview(deleteButton)
        deleteButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        deleteButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.addBtnAction(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func addBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton){
        print("hi")
        if trashIsSelected == false{
            trashIsSelected = true
            imgButton.isHidden = false

            // just change the constant to what you want
            imgButtonWidthConstraint.constant = 50

            imgButton.updateConstraints()

        } else {
            trashIsSelected = false

            imgButtonWidthConstraint.constant = 0

            imgButton.isHidden = true
            imgButton.updateConstraints()
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Just for completeness of the answer, if you were for some reason using constraints where changing a constant would not be enough, you would have to activate and deactivate the constraints. E.g., if you were using `multiplier` to determine `imgButton`'s width, you would have to use this approach (multiplier is an immutable property of the `NSLayoutConstraint`). So therefore creating a constraint:

```
// simply switch the constant between 0 and 50):
imgButtonWidthConstraint = imgButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: someOtherView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0)
imgButtonWidthConstraint.isActive = true
```

And then in `addBtnAction` you would have to do to this:

```
@objc func addBtnAction(_ sender: UIButton){
    print("hi")
    if trashIsSelected == false{
        trashIsSelected = true
        imgButton.isHidden = false

        // first deactivate current constraint
        imgButtonWidthConstraint.isActive = false
        // then create a new one and store it to imgButtonWidthConstraint property (the old one is deactivated, so you don't need a reference to it anymore)
        imgButtonWidthConstraint = imgButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: someOtherView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.75)
        // and activate the new one
        imgButtonWidthConstraint.isActive = true

        imgButton.updateConstraints()

    } else {
        trashIsSelected = false

        // same process again
        imgButtonWidthConstraint.isActive = false
        imgButtonWidthConstraint = imgButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: someOtherView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0)
        imgButtonWidthConstraint.isActive = true

        imgButton.isHidden = true
        imgButton.updateConstraints()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to that, I have resolved what we have been thinking for a long time.